iOS Notification not receiving when there is no notification parameter in the fcm body push notification from server side
When I send the below body to https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
json body to trigger is notified from server side :
{"to":"##receiver_token##","content_available" : true,"mutable_content": true,"data":{"title":"Ram","body":"Hello","title_loc_key":"100","body_loc_key":"Personal Chats"},"priority":"high"}

At least FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {}) is not triggering when I send the above body.
It is working as expected when I send notification instead of data in the body
{"to":"##receiver_token##","content_available" : true,"mutable_content": true,"notification":{"title":"Ram","body":"Hello","title_loc_key":"100","body_loc_key":"Personal Chats"},"priority":"high"}

I only need to send the data parameter in the body but ios couldn't trigger when sending only data in the body.
I tried including below code in the appdelegate.swift

extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any],
                               fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        // Handle notification payload
        print("Received remote notification: \(userInfo)")
    }
}


But still it not getting when data parameter is sent.
I just need to get/trigger the notification when i pass below body
{"to":"##receiver_token##","content_available" : true,"mutable_content": true,"data":{"title":"Ram","body":"Hello","title_loc_key":"100","body_loc_key":"Personal Chats"},"priority":"high"}

